# Wordpress: using elementor editor but wrapped with custom header and foofer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I am using free version of Elementor. And I would like to use Elementor editor inside my "Post" but wrapping the editor with my custom "header" and "footer".

I saw that there is a function called: [`Frontend::apply_builder_in_content`](https://code.elementor.com/methods/elementor-frontend-apply_builder_in_content/).  I wonder, how do I put it in my `single.php/page.php` so that I can have both elementor editor AND my custom "wrapper" of the editor?

Here is my sample `single.php`:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://my_domain_url");

// This function extract the content area that will apply elementor into
list($beginHTML, $endHTML) = explode("_content_area_separator_", $html);

print $beginHTML;

// I expect Elementor is started here: Start
the_post();
the_content();
// I expect Elementor is started here: end

print $endHTML;
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.